# Ghostscript: why must I provide a pdfa_def.ps for PDF/A conversion?

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Ghostscript has documentation that describes [how to create a PDF/A](http://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Ps2pdf.htm#PDFA). I know how to do that.

What I don't understand is why this process is necessary. In particular:

- Why must I specify an output ICC Profile (`-sOutputICCProfile`)? Can't a default be inferred from the choice of color conversion strategy or process color model?
- Why must I provide the *full* file path to the output ICC profile in `PDFA_def.ps`? Why can't Ghostscript assume that I mean one of its own ICC profiles if no path is specified?
- Why do I have to specify both the ICC profile file path and the ICC profile's /OutputConditionIdentifier? Can't one be obtained from the other?
- Why do I have to provide `pdfa_def.ps` which seems like boilerplate  Ghostscript could generate in most cases with reasonable defaults? (The /DOCINFO block could be passed over the command line; the ICC profile block seems to be self-generating based on command line arguments anyway; and the output intent dictionary just needs the color profile name which Ghostscript already knows.)

For that matter, does color conversion apply to images in a document or only to Postscript drawings?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PDF/A implies a colour managed workflow, so :

1) No you cannot infer an ICC profile from the choice of colour conversion strategy, because it won't be correct. You need to specify an OutputICCProfile.

2) The Ghostscript profiles are intended for *input*, ie conversion from a decent representation of the PostScript colour spaces into the CIE XYZ space. Not for conversion **from** XYZ **to** a specific colour space.

3) The ICC profile's name can (usually) be read from the profile's desc tag, but the PDF output code doesn't examine the profile contents, it just embeds it. I presume that by 'name' you mean the human readable description of the profile space, the OutputConditionIdentifier.

4) The content of pdfa_def.ps is not exactly boilerplate, its a PostScript program. Yes we *could* add to the (already massively confusing and incredibly long) list of Ghostscript command line options, but since there is already a mechanism for performing these tasks, using PostScript (the pdfmark operator) we choose to use that for most of the configuration. The parts which cannot be dealt with that way **are** defined as command line paramteres (-dPDFA for example). Programming in PostScript is also considerably more flexible than command line parameters.

Finally colour conversion applies to *everything*, no matter what the input language; PDF, PostScript, XPS, PCL, PXL.

Comment: To clarify, should -sOutputICCProfile generally should be set to the same filename as the /ICCProfile entry in pdfa_def.ps?

Also, I used Ghostscript and Acrobat to create a sRGB PDF/A of a AdobeRGB JPEG. Both programs insert both the sRGB and AdobeRGB profiles, presumably leaving it to the viewer to perform color conversion. Why does ColorConversionStrategy not perform AdobeRGB -> sRGB in this case?

Comment: You should not, normally, set -sOutputICCProfile when creating a PDF/A with pdfa_def.ps. I can't answer your other questoin without seeing the input file and knowing what parameters were used. However, pdfwrite won't create a sRGB PDF file at all, if you ask for sRGB we convert to RGB. Note that its quite legal to include ICCBased colour spaces in a PDF/A file, so its entirely possible that ths is what you've got. In order to 'convert' from 'adobe RGB' to sRGB we would need to convert the colours to CIE and then back, which would hurt performance especially for images.

Comment: Thank you. It looks like it's an ICCbased colorspace.

Comment: I **suspect** but I cannot be sure without knowing a great deal more, that the JPEG itself includes an ICC profile. You cannot use Ghostscript to change a JPEG into a PDF, but you can *program* it to do so (using PostScript). In which case it probably embeds the JPEG unaltered so if it includes an ICC profile, then it will remain afterwards. I imagine Acrobat works similarly.